# Firebase REST orderBy seams not work or documentation is really poor?

Tags: php, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase REST API with PHP Curl.
And i'm using Firebase Database with this rules:

```
"rules": {
    // ...
    "structure" : {
        "pages" : {
           ".indexOn":["order"]
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

And my data is:

```
// ...
"structure" : {
    "pages" : {
       "Some Random String or UID from Firebase" : {
            "some_data" : "string",
            "order" : 0
       },
       "Some Random String 2 or UID from Firebase 2" : {
            "some_data" : "string",
            "order" : 1
       }
       // ... and so on ...
    }
}
```

I Read the doc. from Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).
Trying to filter using orderByChild:

```
GET - https://[my-project].firebaseio.com/structure/pages.json?orderByChild="order"&print=pretty
```

And orderBy:

```
GET - https://[my-project].firebaseio.com/structure/pages.json?orderBy="order"&print=pretty
```

I get the result, but it is not ordered!
Try to change the rules and put it a $key custom and the result and nothing ordered.

I miss something in the doc ? Because i read it many times the data and rules is like the example "dinosaurs".

If some information is missing, please, tell-me to edit and put here.
Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [first documentation page you linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key) contains this warning (scroll up one screen);

> Filtered data is returned unordered: When using the REST API, the
>   filtered results are returned in an undefined order since JSON
>   interpreters don't enforce any ordering. If the order of your data is
>   important you should sort the results in your application after they
>   are returned from Firebase.

Ordering's contribution to filtering occurs when used in conjunction with the other filtering options: `limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt`, `endAt`, and `equalTo`.  The ordering and limiting is done on the server, but when you see the results in a client, they are unordered.

Comment: Thanks for point that! I didnt pay attention this BIG RED alert :( ... So i have to do the order in my PHP before show to client ( i.e. do all the work!!! rsrs ) Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde: I have not used the REST API and was surprised to learn that the results are not sorted.  When an ordered query is done using the Android client SDK, the results _are_ ordered.  I'm curious to learn now how that is done because I would guess the client  SDKs use the REST API.

Comment: i do it on PHP, i have to retrieve the data i want ( all or startAt & endAt cause this filter works well on REST ), then use uasort method in php and use the field i want to sort ( like i use on this question "order" ). Now is working, but is a process that i try to avoid to not process on my server.... but... Firebase do this to us rsrsrsrrs